# Determining throughput from pcap containing flow records

Tags: tshark, netflow

I have a single packet capture (acquired via tcpdump) that contains flow records between an exporter and a collector.

I want to determine throughput across a given interface using the bytes (octets) field in the v9 record. I have filtered down to the network that I want like so:

```
tshark -r input.pcap -Y "ip.src == X.X.X.X" -F pcap -w filtered.pcap
```

I further filtered to the interface that I needed like so:

```
tshark -r filtered.pcap -Y "cflow.inputint == Y" -F pcap -w filtered2.pcap
```

I'm lost after that. Is there a better tool to aggregate across the flows to get throughput?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to print netflow fields and then process the results.

For example:

```
tshark -T fields -e cflow.version -e cflow.srcaddr -e cflow.dstaddr -e cflow.octets -e cflow.timedelta -e cflow.abstimestart
```

Field names are visible in wireshark status bar when you select packet details.

---

Better option:

1. install or compile https://github.com/phaag/nfdump with `--enable-readpcap` flag.
2. process your pcap `nfcapd -f <path to your pcap file> -l <path to output directory> -T all`
3. count statistics `nfdump -o extended -r <path to output directory>`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I did something similar to this. I filtered my packets and then dumped them to JSON using `-e <field> ... -T json` like in your example. I then used this file to post-process what I needed in Python. Thanks for the reply!